# Simple Javascript function onload

Tags: javascript

Here I have a function

```
function photoLoop() {
fade1L('3000');fade1M('3500');fade1R('4000');show2L('3000');show2M('3500');show2R('4000');
}
```

When the page loads this function is called `<body onload="photoLoop();>`

At this point these functions are run until it reaches the end i.e show2R('4000');

My problem is I want it to now go back to fade1L('3000'); and start over.

How can this be done, with out crashing IE?

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery Effects library and make use of the 'callback' functionality

e.g.
http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout().

You can do

```
setTimeout(photoLoop, 1000); // call the function after 1 second.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function directly, do the following which will repeat the function at the specified interval:

```
setInterval(photoLoop, 1000);
```

Where 1000 is the interval to repeat the function in milliseconds. You will presumably want to set this to the total duration of these animations (21000ms at a guess).